# How to export 'Sql File' of a Table using C# code

Tags: c#, oracle

I have developed a school management system, which is connected to a database. Now, I want to take backup of tables.

My idea is to generate an SQL file of each table that will later be used for backup. I achieved this goal manually in Oracle SQL Developer (attached a screen shot), first exporting the SQL file and then importing those files. Now I want to do this programmatically using C#. I have searched a lot on Google, but found nothing useful.

[image: screenshot of oracle sql developer]

Comment: Why not use the backup commands?

Comment: Where is the code you have already tried? No code => no help

Comment: Backups should be done server side. What is the database ? `MSSQL`, `MySQL`, `SQLite` ?

Comment: @Franck Oracle. If you squint, you can see it in the screenshot ;).

Comment: I'd say Oracle is the database, as oracle sql developer is used.

Comment: Oracle has these features built in. Don't rebuild them.

Comment: In sqldev, we do this with a bunch of code that you would have to replicate to perform the same from c#. _if_ the real exercise is to automate, the same can be done with SQLcl.

Comment: in short, how can i generate sql file of tables programmatically??

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if you want to take full backup including table data, stored proc, views etc., You could go for SQL script

```
BACKUP DATABASE School_Management TO DISK = 'D:\SQL Backup\SchoolManagement\SM_20180314.bak'    WITH FORMAT,  
  MEDIANAME = 'SM_Backups',  
  NAME = 'Full Backup of School_Management';
```

You could run the above script from your C# code, passing the backup path as a parameter. Let me know if you need more detail

Comment: No, it wont. I din't really notice the database being Oracle

Comment: This is why it's always best to get clarification on questions before answering...

Comment: Thanks for pointing out Mike, will ensure the question is well read next time :)

Answer (score 0):

Although **NOT** a proper backup, a simple EXP utility (yes, the *original* export, not Data Pump) might do the job just fine.

Why the *original* EXP? Because you can run it on your computer, it will export the whole user (tables, procedures, packages, ...) and create a file on your computer. Data Pump, a modern *export* utility is much more powerful, but - in order to use it - you have to have access to the database server (i.e. its *directory* which stores exported files. Read more about all that stuff in documentation).

So, a small demonstration of how it looks like - I'm going to export my SCOTT user:

```
c:\Temp>exp scott/tiger@xe file=scott.dmp

Export: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Sri O×u 14 20:13:30 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.


Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
Export done in EE8MSWIN1250 character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR character set
server uses AL32UTF8 character set (possible charset conversion)
. exporting pre-schema procedural objects and actions
. exporting foreign function library names for user SCOTT
. exporting PUBLIC type synonyms
. exporting private type synonyms
. exporting object type definitions for user SCOTT
About to export SCOTT's objects ...
. exporting database links
. exporting sequence numbers
. exporting cluster definitions
. about to export SCOTT's tables via Conventional Path ...
. . exporting table                           DEPT          4 rows exported
. . exporting table                            EMP         12 rows exported

<snip>

. exporting synonyms
. exporting views
. exporting stored procedures
. exporting operators
. exporting referential integrity constraints
. exporting triggers
. exporting indextypes
. exporting bitmap, functional and extensible indexes
. exporting posttables actions
. exporting materialized views
. exporting snapshot logs
. exporting job queues
. exporting refresh groups and children
. exporting dimensions
. exporting post-schema procedural objects and actions
. exporting statistics
Export terminated successfully with warnings.

c:\Temp>

c:\Temp>dir scott.dmp
 Volume in drive C is OSDisk
 Volume Serial Number is 7635-F892

 Directory of c:\Temp

14.03.2018.  20:13         1.310.720 scott.dmp
               1 File(s)      1.310.720 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  346.085.478.400 bytes free

c:\Temp>
```

The resulting .DMP file can now be transferred to some other database, imported (using the IMP command) and you'll have it up & running in a matter of minutes (OK, that depends on whether the *environment* on the new database is *friendly* to user you imported - for example, non-existing users you access via database links, etc. might spoil the joy, but that's another story).

Apart from that, investigate usage of RMAN (Recovery MANager):

> Recovery Manager (RMAN) is an Oracle Database client that performs
>   backup and recovery tasks on your databases and automates
>   administration of your backup strategies. It greatly simplifies
>   backing up, restoring, and recovering database files.

which is a proper way to backup your database; though, might be an overkill if you just want to "save" one user's objects.